# subset df according nested list while there is a white space

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame and I would like to subset it according specific values. When I have tried to do it, there is problem because of the white space inside the values in `sample_df$mentions`.

I used this script for subsetting the data frame:

```
sample_list <- list()
for (i in colnames(sample_name)){
  sample_list <- sapply(sample_df$mentions, function(x)any(x %in% sample_name[[i]]))
  new_sample_df <- sample_df[sample_list,]
}
```

I have tried `strsplit` function to get rid of the space but it has created other problems.

```
sample_df$mentions <- strsplit(as.charater(sample_df$mentions),"[[:space:]]")
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

My expected outcome should be like this:

```
                                                            mentions  screen_name
5          islambey1453,  hamzayerlikaya,  tahaayhan,  hidoturkoglu15  ak_Furkan54
10 nurhandnci,  SSSBBL777,  serkanacar007,  Chequevera06,  kubilayy81 tanrica_gaia
```

sample_name reproducible data:

```
sample_name <- structure(list(Name = structure(2:1, .Label = c("hamzayerlikaya", 
                                                               "SSSBBL777"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

sample_df reproducible data:

```
sample_df <- structure(list(mentions = list(character(0), "srgnsnmz92", character(0), 
                               "Berivan_Aslan_", c("islambey1453", " hamzayerlikaya", " tahaayhan", 
                                                   " hidoturkoglu15"), character(0), "themarginale", character(0), 
                               character(0), c("nurhandnci", " SSSBBL777", " serkanacar007", 
                                               " Chequevera06", " kubilayy81")), screen_name = c("SaadetYakar", 
                                                                                                 "beraydogru", "EL_Turco_DLC", "hebunagel", "ak_Furkan54", "zaferakyol011", 
                                                                                                 "melmitem", "mobbingabla", "BekarKronik", "tanrica_gaia")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                           10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the 'Name' and use that in `grepl`, `Reduce` it to a single logical vector and subset the rows of 'sample_df'

```
sample_df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(as.character(sample_name$Name), 
      grepl, x = sample_df$mentions)),]
#                                                           mentions  screen_name
#5          islambey1453,  hamzayerlikaya,  tahaayhan,  hidoturkoglu15  ak_Furkan54
#10 nurhandnci,  SSSBBL777,  serkanacar007,  Chequevera06,  kubilayy81 tanrica_gaia
```

NOTE: This would work with any `length` of 'Name' column

---

Another option is  `regex_inner_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)
regex_inner_join(sample_df, sample_name, by = c("mentions" = "Name")) %>% 
      select(mentions, screen_name)
#                                                          mentions  screen_name
#1         islambey1453,  hamzayerlikaya,  tahaayhan,  hidoturkoglu15  ak_Furkan54
#2 nurhandnci,  SSSBBL777,  serkanacar007,  Chequevera06,  kubilayy81 tanrica_gaia
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `mentions` is a list we can use `sapply` and select only those rows in `sample_df` where `any` of the `mentions` has `Name` in it.

```
sample_df[sapply(sample_df$mentions, function(x) any(grepl(pattern, x))), ]

#                                                             mentions  screen_name
#5          islambey1453,  hamzayerlikaya,  tahaayhan,  hidoturkoglu15  ak_Furkan54
#10 nurhandnci,  SSSBBL777,  serkanacar007,  Chequevera06,  kubilayy81 tanrica_gaia
```

where `pattern` is

```
pattern = paste0("\\b", sample_name$Name, "\\b", collapse = "|")
```

Comment: As far as I understood from pattern, it add space into the sample_name$Name, doesn't it!

Comment: @eabanoz yes...so that `SSSBBL777` is not matched with `SSSBBL77787` or `ASSSBBL777`

Comment: I didn't mention about it but I have different data frame and some of them don't have this problem. In this case, it isn't a good solution for me. Thanks for everything by the way.

Comment: @eabanoz This works on the data you have shown in your example. If you have got data which is different from what you have shown then this may or may not work.